# NSTimer, to retain or not to retain

Tags: iphone, nstimer

This is something that has puzzled me for awhile.

I have a NSTimer, added to the currentRunLoop, and if I don't retain it, it crashes.

```
NSTimer *timer = [[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self selector:@selector(tryUnion:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO] retain];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

I have read that I don't need to retain it, as addTimer to the NSRunLoop does that.

later I invalidate and release (if I don't retain above, I don't release below- that's the crashing case):

```
- (void) tryUnion:(NSTimer*)aTimer {
[aTimer invalidate];
[aTimer release];
}
```

My questions are
1) How should I write this, if its possible to do what i've done without the retain/release.
2) analyze flags this or a potential leak of the object in "timer". As written here, is there the possibility of leaks, or is it just that analyzer isn't smart enough to know that there is a release in the function called by the timer?

Comment: Looks like what I should really be doing is this: [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self selector:@selector(tryUnion:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO]; with no runloop scheduling, and no invalidate in the selector. Yes/No anyone? I get no errors or analyzer complaints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule is, don't release it if you didn't retain it.  [Here is a similar question which talks about that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171393/what-is-the-first-step-in-nstimer-release-and-invalidate)  So in your example code I would suggest not retaining it, and not releasing it.

But that's not your issue.  Your issue is that you've created a non-repeating timer.  You don't need to invalidate those, they invalidate themselves after they fire.  From the [NSTimer docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html):

> **repeats** 
>   If YES, the timer will
>   repeatedly reschedule itself until
>   invalidated. If NO, the timer will be
>   invalidated after it fires.

So you should neither retain/release that timer, nor invalidate it.  Fire and forget.

As an aside, if you use `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`, the adding of the timer to the runloop is done for you as well.  So your whole thing would be like:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self selector:@selector(tryUnion:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Your timer function doesn't need to do anything with aTimer, just do whatever thing your timer is supposed to do; the timer will be invalidated and released without further intervention.

Answer (score 1):

Calling invalidate on a timer releases it so you don't need to have another release statement. See the docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

Comment: Hm, is the problem that since my timer doesn't repeat, I don't need to invalidate? because if I don't put retain (AND don't put release) it crashes when it runs the selector (with invalidate)

Comment: after testing I find that I get the same crash at release by the runloop without invalidate in the selector

Answer (score 1):

Well you're right in that the `NSTimer` shouldn't have to be retained. The class method `+(NSTimer *)timerWithInterval` should, by rule, `autorelease` it's reference.

But NSTimer's `invalidate` message removes itself from the `NSRunLoop` and that releases it's reference (the only one left at the time). Your second `[aTimer release]` call is the cause of the crash.

Comment: No, as stated in my post, If I put the timer in *timer with retain, I am not putting release in the callback. without BOTH retain and release, it fails with an error traced to >_CFRunLoopTimerDeallocate>CFRelease.